# UILabel inside a UITableViewCell is cut, i can see only the half top part of the first line

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

i need to put comment in a tableview. i am using UILabel to enter the text but for some reason i can see only the first line of the text and only the upper part of the line.
only if i have a text of 1 line the text is shown proberly.

here is my code:

```
    cell.comments.text = @"some text here";
    cell.comments.numberOfLines = 0;
    [cell.comments setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    cell.comments.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Exo-Regular" size:17];
```

resizing the cell:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

NSString *cellComment=[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"some text here"];
CGSize size = [cellComment sizeWithAttributes:
               @{NSFontAttributeName:
                     [UIFont fontWithName:@"Exo-Regular" size:17]}];

return 40+size.height;
```

i tried resizing the UILable but it didnt work:

```
cell.comments.frame=CGRectMake(49, 29, 222, MAXFLOAT);
```

also tried with a costum size for height and it didnt work.

and this is how it looks like:

i cant post images yet because i need more reputation so here is a link for the image:

[image]

Comment: you are aware that we cannot access images in your mailbox?

Comment: where is the code for resizing the cell where for resizing the label? Did u try to search for a solution at all?

Comment: added the resizing of the cell and the label, i checked for a lot of hours, please remove the -1

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the code you use to declare your cell?

You can try using sizetofit like below(in order to usesizetofit you must turn autolayout off)

```
YourLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
[YourLabel sizeToFit];
```

If you are using Interface builder:
Or you can try selecting your label in the storyboard go to the attribute inspector and then select 0 as the number of lines from there.

When typing within the label using IB, use "alt-return" to insert a return and go to the next line.

Comment: i tried sizetofil and thats what i recieved:http://postimg.org/image/m4y8jdw27/

i tried to use: cell.comments.frame=CGRectMake

but it didnt work

Comment: CGSize s = [yourString sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(width, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

Comment: sizeWithFont is deprecated in ios7

Comment: i need to show all the text in the uilabel by lines and its not working. i have width of 222 and random height which i already have. the uilabel is set in a nib file in a costum cell. im using autolayout. i tried without autolayout but nothing good came up. the cell size is changing and there is enough room for the text to e shown. but as in the pictures i cant seem to put the text in the right spot/show all of it

Comment: never mind found the problem. i needed to add it as subview of cell.contentview